# php Update multidimensional array based on values from another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have 2 different multidimensional array that are structured in the following way

ARRAY 1

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => john
        [1] => AUTHOR
        [2] => PUBLISHER
    )
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Smith
        [1] => AUTHOR
        [2] => PUBLISHER
    )
    )
```

ARRAY 2

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => John
        [1] => www.john.com
        [2] => D
    )

        [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Smith
        [1] => smith.com
        [2] => D
    )
    )
```

I would like two check if the value "john" from Array1 is available in array2. If it's the case, i retrieve the value of "www.john.com" in array2 and insert it in array 1

This is what i would like to achieve

FINAL ARRAY

ARRAY 1

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => john
        [1] => www.john.com
        [2] => AUTHOR
        [3] => PUBLISHER
    )
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Paul
        [1] => AUTHOR
        [2] => PUBLISHER
    )
    )
```

The array is dynamic, i put static values just to show what i would like to acheive.

Any help on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you, but see comment below:

```
$arrayFirst = array(
     arraey('John', 'AUTHOR', 'PUBLISHER',),
     array('Smith', 'AUTHOR', 'PUBLISHER')) ;

$arraySecond = array(
     array('John', 'www.john.com', 'D'),
     array('Smith', 'smith.com', 'D'));

foreach ($arrayFirst as  $kye => $subArrayFirst){

  foreach ($arraySecond as $subArraySecond){
   if(in_array($subArrayFirst[0], $subArraySecond)) {
               $arrayFirst[$kye][] =  $subArraySecond[1];
          }            
    }    
}

var_dump($arrayFirst);
```

But in this case it is important the position of authow name and address

Answer (score 0):

```
$s1 = [
    ['John', 'AUTHOR', 'PUBLISHER'],
    ['Smith', 'AUTHOR', 'PUBLISHER']
    ];

$s2 = [
       ['John', 'www.john.com', 'D'],
       ['Smith', 'smith.com', 'D']
    ];

foreach ($s1 as &$info) {
    $name = $info[0];
    foreach ($s2 as $info2) {
        if (in_array($name, $info2)) {
            $url = $info2[1];
            $info[] = $url;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and fast way.

```
for($i=0;i<=Array1.length;i++){
for($j=0;j<=Array2.length;j++){

if (Array1[0][0] == Array2[i][j]){
echo Array2[i][j];
Array1[0][1] = Array2[i][j];
break;
break;
}


}
}
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which checks if one item from array1 is avaiable in array2:

```
function arrayTwoContains($element)
{
  foreach($array2 as $elemFrom2)
  {
    if(strtolower($element[0])==strtolower($elemFrom2[0])) //if the names from array1 and array 2 are equal: return element two
    {
      return $elemFrom2;
    }
  }
   return false;
}
```

Then you can build a loop where you run through array1 and if arrayTwoContains() returns not false, you put the values in a new array.

```
$fused = array(); // your new array
$key = 0; //current index of new array
foreach($array1 as $element)
{
  if($elemFromTwo = arrayTwoContains($element))
  {
    $elementToInsert = array();
    $elementToInsert[0] = $element[0];
    $elementToInsert[1] = $elemFromTwo[1];
    $elementToInsert[2] = $element[1];
    $elementToInsert[3] = $element[2];
    $fused[$key] = $elementToInsert;
    $key++;
  }
}
```

I hope this works, I haven't done anything in PHP since months ;)